# Display image from array in python

Tags: python, image

I have been trying to convert 20x20 grayscale image into numpy array of pixel intensities. However, when I displayed it, the image was completely different from its original (noisy, meaningless chunks of white pixels on a black background. The original image was a handwriten white 'x' on a black background). The code I used is shown bellow.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("testing_data/" + 'x' + "_" + '5' + ".jpg")
img.show()
print(len(list(img.getdata())))         #prints 400
a = np.array(list(img.getdata()))
img = Image.fromarray(a.reshape(20, 20), 'L')
img.show()
```

First img.show() call displays image correctly, second one does not. What have I done incorrectly?

P.S. after some debugging, I have found that there was a problem after transformation of list into numpy array.

Comment: Post then code directly here as text. Never post images of code.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see what the data's representation looked like through each step of transformation? Also, you must include the actual image library you used. Right now, your example is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 'Completely different from its original' is not a precise problem statement, if at all.